# Can we increase the text for push notifications we send to Google?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If we send push notifications to user using FCM, can we increase the push notification height to add more text?

Also, can we persist the push notification to more than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Big View Styles](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html).

> Notifications in the notification drawer appear in two main visual
>   styles, normal view and big view. The big view of a notification only
>   appears when the notification is expanded. This happens when the
>   notification is at the top of the drawer, or the user clicks the
>   notification.

To customize the Big View Style notification size, you can use [`bigContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView)

> A large-format version of [`contentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentView), giving the Notification
>   an opportunity to show more detail. The system UI may choose to show
>   this instead of the normal content view at its discretion. As of N,
>   this field may be null. The expanded notification view is determined
>   by the inputs to [`Notification.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html); a custom RemoteViews can
>   optionally be supplied with
>   [`setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCustomBigContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)).

For further studies on Notifications here is a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). The documentation will let you know the considerations of design and other important technical aspects of creating notifications.

For the persistence of push notification, try to check this code from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096475/android-i-need-to-delay-a-notification).

```
// SLEEP 5 SECONDS HERE ...
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() { 
          // createNotification(SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[0]), context);
          updateActivity();
     } 
}, 5000);
```